# code EISGIT ... node_modules/sitemap: Appears to be a git repo or submodule

Tags: npm, travis-ci

recently I started [getting errors on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/builds/556643875) in the form of

```
npm ERR! path /home/travis/build/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/node_modules/sitemap
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git /home/travis/build/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/node_modules/sitemap: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /home/travis/build/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/node_modules/sitemap
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.
```

Looking around the net that error appears to happen if one of the dependences has a `.git` folder inside.

Checking locally though I see no extra `.git` folders

```
$ rm -rf node_modules 
$ npm install
added 540 packages from 362 contributors and audited 1735 packages in 11.102s
$ find . -name ".git"
./.git
$
```

Checking [the build history](https://travis-ci.org/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/builds) it started failing after [this change](https://github.com/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/commit/7d7b9ddcd1c804506be3babd8b6deda5f05da208). There is nothing related to the build in that change. No build dependencies changed, nothing.

I thought maybe the issue was related to a node or npm version but looking in the log both success and failure are using the same versions

```
$ node --version
v12.6.0
$ npm --version
6.9.0
$ nvm --version
0.34.0
```

What else can I look into to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know if this was why. I added in `package-lock.json` files to my repo and 2 dependent repos. I was in the habit of not using them because they are/were buggy when used across platform. Adding them in and the problem went away. No idea if that was the actual reason or just coincidence. They haven't been needed for the last many years so it seems more like coincidence to me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt like that you have a git submodule. In your case .git in sitemap. So go to your proeject folder and navigate to sitemap  (home/travis/build/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/node_modules/sitemap) and copy .git to your desktop, then install the npm package in your project and then go paste the .git in sitemap back. 
Worked for me =)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is closed now.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view/issues/73

run **rm -rf node_modules/*/.git/** command then try to install npm library.

Comment: As point out in my quesiton there were no .git folders in my node_modules folder